# Box2D vector () operator

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, box2d

I was reading the Box2D source code. In `b2Vec2` there is the `()` operator being overloaded, but I did not understand what it is supposed to do. I read the manual and the reference of this method but still did not get what it means to `Read from an indexed element` and `write to an indexed element`, and both methods have the same body `return (&x)[i]`. What does this mean and do?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a previous comment (but it was removed for some reason), I got an idea and tested it out, and it turns out this will allow me to access and write to x and y using indices 0 and 1 respectively.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class clazz {
public:
    float x, y;

    clazz(float x_, float y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}

    float operator () (int i) const {
        return (&x)[i];
    }

    float& operator () (int i) {
        return (&x)[i];
    }
};

int main() {
    clazz f (3, 4);

    cout << "f: x = " << f(0) << " y = " << f(1) << endl; // printed => f: x = 3 y = 4

    f(0) = 6;
    f(1) = 6;

    cout << "f: x = " << f(0) << " y = " << f(1) << endl; // printed => f: x = 6 y = 6

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you found out it's an accessor function to the individual elements in the vector class. The reason there are two functions is due to const functions need access to the value of the element without needing to modify it. Note that you could return a const reference here as well but this is not necessary in your case since it is operating on a float.

Hopefully there are asserts in place for making sure that code isn't indexing out of the range since that is quite easy to do, especially when you have are using a signed variable like in your example.